# Division with different numeric types

Tags: sql-server, teradata

I am trying to calculate a rate by using two variables from a subquery and i want my result to have three values after the decimal.

Variables:

calls -- type(integer)

boxes -- type(float)

```
       ROUND((calls / boxes) * 100.0, 3) Call_Rate
```

only returns two decimal points

when i use

```
    (CAST(calls AS DECIMAL(10,3)) / (boxes AS DECIMAL(10,3)) * 100.0 Call_Rate
```

this code returns three digits after the decimal but the third digit is always 0, so it is being rounded.

When converting both variables to float, it also returns just 2 values after decimal.

Is there any way to perform this operation to have it return 3 decimal points.

Answer (score 1):

```
(CAST(calls AS DECIMAL(10,5)) / (boxes AS DECIMAL(10,5)) * 100.0 Call_Rate
```

When you multiply by 100, you are shifting the decimal point to the right two places, so you need two more places in your decimal conversion.

Comment: (10,5) actually returned a numeric overflow error, but (13,5) returned the result i was looking for. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The 1st calculation actually rounds to *three* digits, but you probably run this query from SQL Assistant and there's a default precision of *two*. You can change it in *Tools > Options > Number of decimal places to display for Float columns*

The result of the 2nd calculation is based on Teradata's calculation rules for decimals, see [DECIMAL Result Data Type](https://info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_16_00/SQL_Reference/B035-1145-160K/imx1472240927826.html#wwID0EFVAI)

In short: *Multiply first, then divide*

```
100 * CAST(calls AS DECIMAL(10,3)) / CAST(boxes AS DECIMAL(10,3)) AS Call_Rate
```

Or keep the Float and do a final cast:

```
cast( 100 * calls / boxes as decimal(10,3))
```